# Amazon S3 Downloading .mp3 and .wav files as .zip

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I send out music files (.mp3 and .wav) and give the recipient the option to download individual files as .mp3 or .wav, or a bundle as .zip.   I upload all these to my s3 account, and force download with PHP.  All has been fine until about two weeks ago, when the individual .wav and .mp3 files that I never zipped up were being downloaded as .zips.

Users click the option to download the individual tracks as .mp3 and .wav and every time a .zip file downloads, which obviously doesn't extract as it's not a valid zip.  Renaming the zip to a .wav or .mp3 (depending on what was downloaded) works fine.

For nearly five years this has worked fine until two weeks ago.

Any possible help please as I am lost?

Comment: Check the `content-type` metadata on the objects to confirm that it is being set correctly.

Comment: It's                         header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

Comment: That might be causing the problem, but it wouldn't explain why it changed recently. Have you tried from different browsers? Can you use <a href="music.mp3" download="music.mp3">download</a>` instead?

Comment: Sadly not, the way my system is I limit each person to two download attempts per track and the url to get the file is passed if they have an attempt left.